# How to accomplish a logical OR in bash

Tags: bash, logic

I'd like to have a command only execute if the preceding command's exit status was not 0.

i.e.
Command 1 ^ Command 2
where Command 2 is only executed when Command 1 fails.

Comment: You know there is no way to make exclusive or short-circuit right (because no matter what the value of the left operand is, the result will always also depend on the right operand)? What you're describing is ordinary or.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this, use the double-pipe (`||`) operator.

```
touch /asdf/fdasfds/fdasfdas || echo "Couldn't touch."
```

The second command is only executed when the first command returns non-zero, exactly as you specified.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see this. Dumb oversight on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be mentioned that that OR doesn't have the same meaning as XOR ("exclusive or"). See truth table below.

```
       "or"          "xor"
P  Q  (( $P || $Q ))  (( ($P && ! $Q) || (! $P && $Q) ))
0  0  0               0 
0  1  1               1
1  0  1               1
1  1  1               0
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
command1 || command2
```